# Wordpress invalid line with foreach statement

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, tumblr

So for my personal portfolio website, I had written a script to integrate Tumblr posts within a Wordpress page. It was working fine till the other day. But now I get an invalid line error from Wordpress.

at first I thought it was the new tumblr API but everything works fine on my local MAMP and WAMP setups, but online it breaks. No recent updates to cause that.So I'm at a loss.

The broken page can be found: http://www.dgovil.com/blog/ and my code for that page is here: http://pastebin.com/5wYy2Zch

I really can't figure out what may be wrong, since my local installs all seem to work fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated. My blog doesn't really have much stuff on it, but I'd like to get it working for when I do want to push it more.

Thanks!

Comment: **$jsondata = json_decode($result,true);** what it returns

Comment: @gowri I believe that it's a remnant from when I was doing tests within the script, but I could be wrong. Was hacked out of another JSON script when I was teaching myself.

Answer (score 0):

`$posts` doesn't have any values in it/is not an array.

Put `var_dump($posts);` a line above that foreach statement and see what it returns.

Comment: No luck, all I get is another line saying NULL above the same error, but the Tumblr JSON API is up and working on my MAMP install. Weird.

Thanks though

Comment: Then it looks like there's something wrong with your json data.

Comment: Hmmm, could be related to the new Tumblr API.
Just weird because the script does execute fine on a local install, but I'll probably rewrite it for the new API which is a lot cleaner

Comment: What about var_dump($result); ? There's really something wrong with json data.

Comment: it returns string(0) "" 
so I guess the JSON it's receiving must be messed up.